# Convert Select Query into CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS Previous_Live_Members, m.HomeBranch, m.LocationName    
FROM
    AX.Mem  M 
WHERE
    m.ActiveStart < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)
    AND (m.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0) OR M.ActiveEnd IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    m.HomeBranch, m.LocationName
```

I already converted but results are different. Might be some issue in my query. I want to convert simple query into CTE table.

```
WITH CTE_A AS 
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE 
               WHEN M.ActiveStart < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)
                    AND M.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0) OR M.ActiveEnd IS NULL
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
            END) AS Previous_No_of_Live_Member,
        M.HomeBranch,
        M.LocationName
    FROM
        AX.Mem M 
    GROUP BY 
        M.HomeBranch, M.LocationName 
)
SELECT
    Previous_No_of_Live_Member,
    HomeBranch,
    LocationName
FROM  
    CTE_A
```

Comment: Hi John, Why dont just copy the code of the first query into the cte?  `code`. The case when and the where are two different things.

Comment: Actually this is not single query, I have some others calculation with it. But this query part results are different from the orignal query.

Comment: both of your query are not even the same. How would you expect to get the same result ? To convert a `select` query to `cte` is very straint forward : `with cte as ( {select query} ) select * from cte;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CTE version is missing a pair of parenthesis.

You are using a query on `ActiveEnd` where `(ActiveEnd > ... OR ActiveEnd IS NULL)`.  This should be in parenthesis in the CTE version too.

Compare this line

```
...
and (m.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0) or M.ActiveEnd is null)
```

with the CTE version

```
...
AND 
M.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0) 
                          or M.ActiveEnd is null then 1 else 0 end)
```

I think it should be (indicated with `^` where I think parenthesis should go):

```
...
AND 
(M.ActiveEnd > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0) 
^                         or M.ActiveEnd is null) then 1 else 0 end)
                                                ^
```